# I Have a Major Problem

Tags: knowledge, pattern

For my final university project, I am recording the majors of *popular* students in my year. Including students who do not have a real major.
 However, I am presenting tomorrow and I am missing some of my data! I have the list of students I interviewed, but I have forgotten which major they belong in.

> Can you help me sort the students into their correct major(or lack of major) so I can give my presentation!

> **FIRST NAMES**
> Winston
> Al
> Bob
> Alice
> Ernest
> Erwin
> Elizabeth
> Frederick
> Gabriel
> Hans
> John
> Ivan
> Martin
> Max
> My Mom?
> Rico
> Rudy
> Teddy

> **LAST INITIAL**
> B B C D E F K K K M M P P R R S S S

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's your list with most initials and majors in place. I also added their ages and their personal best of tetris lines scored in a single game. (I think those were some of your interview questions.)

> ```
>  Name       Initial Major       Age Tetris PB
>  Winston    C       literature   19 53
>  Al         E       physics      19 21
>  Bob        D       literature   20 16
>  Alice      M       literature   20 13
>  Ernest     R       chemistry    19 08
>  Erwin      S       physics      19 33
>  Elizabeth  B       medicine     20 09
>  Frederick  S       chemistry    19 58/80
>  Gabriel    M       literature   19 82
>  Hans       S/K?    medicine     19 35 or 53
>  John       B       physics      19 56/72
>  Ivan       P       medicine     19 04
>  Martin     K       no major     19 64
>  Max        P       physics      19 18
>  My Mom?            no major     19 79
>  Rico       F       physics      19 38
>  Rudy       K       literature   19 08
>  Teddy      R       no major     19 06
> ```

You seem to have [interviewed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates) both John and Frederick twice, and I think Gabriel's initial should actually be G. I couldn't figure out your mom's initial, nor that of Hans's, but I think I got their majors though.

Comment: Great spot (and 'Tetris PB' made me laugh out loud when I realised what the data actually represented and how facetious you were being...!). Of course it's entirely possible that the OP may think of [this person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_Teresa) as their 'mother', whose initial might be considered 'B'...

Comment: @Stiv yeah, that's who I had pegged as OP's mom. (Since this is the internet, let's make it absolutely clear that I did *not* peg OP's mom.) Using that initial would kind of make sense. That would mean I must have misidentified John, whose initial would then have to be S, his major literature, and his Tetris PB 62. That would also nail down Hans as Hans K (53), for a complete match on the initials, so you are almost certainly correct. Not going to edit though, [John B is good enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_B._Goodenough).

Comment: what does 'tetris' in your answer mean?

Comment: @defectedWBC It's a [very popular computer game](https://pastebin.com/zHDUVyY0) created by Alexey Pajitnov in 1984. :-)

Comment: You are indeed correct @Bass. rot13(jbhyq lbh zvaq fcryyvat bhg gur fghqragf ragver anzrf. Nyfb, Fgvi jnf pbeerpg nf gb gur vavgvny bs "zl Zbz". Nyfb, gur bgure barf lbh zragvbarq va gur pbzzragf znl or punatrq gb gurve erfcrpgvir ynfg anzrf.) That will earn you the check!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give their full names in the post.
Winston C.        Winston Churchill
Al E.                    Albert Einstein
Bob D.                 Bob Dylan
Ernest R.             Ernest Rutherford
Erwin S.               Erwin Schrodinger
Frederick S.         Frederick Senger
Max P.                  Max Planck
Rudy K.              Rudyard Kipling
Teddy R.           Teddy Roosevelt
Alice M.             Alice Munro
Rico F.               Enrico Fermi
John B.             John Bannister Goodenough
Ivan P.                Ivan Pavlov
Elizabeth B.      Elizabeth Blackwell
Hans S.             Hans Selye
Martin K.          Martin Luther King Jr
My mom?         Mother Teresa
Gabriel G.         Gabriel Garcia Marquez
All thanks to @Stiv and @Bass

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I cannot accept it. Bass has answered this question correctly first. Also, he has the correct names for each "student". Some of these names or wrong as Stiv and Bass have found the correct ones. Each name has to match with the last initials provided, which would make some of these wrong.

Comment: I didn't want a green check but would you mind compiling all answer at one place. That would be great help. Also does the Nobel Prize mean interview here??

Comment: Well did I really contribute anything??

Comment: @Bass has found the answers to every part of this question between his comments and his answer. I am not going to answer my own question as he already did! I hope his answer will clear up any confusion you have :)

Comment: Bass has already found that, that answer would not work for each student to have an unique last initial. This answer does not contribute anything new to Bass's answer.

Comment: Ha ha! By the way good puzzle.

Comment: May I know why you didn't gave a green check to @Bass since what I decoded in rot 13 was that he had not gave all the full names.

Comment: I have not given the check *yet*, because he has not  added the final parts of the solution he found.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks for clarifying everything.